# SQL: Conditional Field output based on another field's value

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have an interesting situation. my Table has a numeric field called "Discount". It's an integer. My table has another boolean field called "isPercent".

I would like to SELECT the discount field, let's assume the value is 50.

If isPercent is TRUE, I'd like to output it as "50%", else I'd like to output it cast to Money "$50".

How do I 'conditional select' this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the boolean value stored. Simply do an if on it and concat the correct sign :

---

**MySQL**

```
select if(isPercent, concat(discount, '%'), concat('$', discount)) from ...
```

---

**PostgreSQL**

```
SELECT CASE 
  WHEN isPercent THEN discount || '%'
  ELSE '$' || discount END
FROM ...
```